# PySpark JDBC Write to MySQL (TiDB)

Tags: pyspark, tidb

I am trying to write a pyspark dataframe (Millions of row) to TIDB, (Spark 2.3)

```
df.write.format('jdbc').options(
  url='jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<table>',
  driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
  dbtable='<tablename>',
  user='<username>',
  password='<password>',
  batchsize = 30000,
  truncate = True
).mode('overwrite').save()
```

However, all I keep getting is this error

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: statement count 5001 exceeds the transaction limitation, autocommit = false
....
....
....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: statement count 5001 exceeds the transaction limitation, autocommit = false
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: From the TiDB documentation: `If a transaction does not roll back or commit after the number of statements exceeds `stmt-count-limit`, TiDB returns the `statement count 5001 exceeds the transaction limitation, autocommit = false` error.`

Comment: I am not understanding, how can I pass commit with spark

Comment: You need to set `autocommit` to `true` on your JDBC Driver.

Comment: can you show me an example, how do you do this, do I need this in url param?

Comment: First, have you tried to decrease batch size to 5000?

Comment: it is giving the same error

Comment: yes tried, it is giving the same error

Comment: Try adding ?rewriteBatchedStatements=true to your JDBC URI or options. Also, check your conf/tidb.yml file (stmt-count-limit parameter)

Comment: @AlexandreJuma - this worked `?rewriteBatchedStatements=true ` can you please write this as an answer, I want to accept it

Comment: I am also facing this issue now `The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
`

Comment: That's usually related to: (1) Wrong JDBC URI (2) Connectivity issues such as firewalls (3) Database is down (4) Your connection was open for so long and idle that the DB disconnected you (5) You stressed the DB so much that it ceased to respond at a networking level

Comment: `The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. ` Hi @HardikGupta, does this error occur for every sql? and does any error in tidb.log file in this error thrown? could you convenience give you current jdbc url value(you can mask the ip/port/password)? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `?rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to your JDBC URI so that the DML statements are batched. Not only the write will be faster but you wont hit your database transaction limit so easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add option to set "isolationLevel" as none, it will avoid the limitation of transaction

```
df.write.format('jdbc').options(
  url='jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<table>',
  driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
  dbtable='<tablename>',
  user='<username>',
  password='<password>',
  batchsize = 30000,
  truncate = True,
  isolationLevel = None
).mode('overwrite').save()
```